# Setting width of spreadsheet cell using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to set the width of a cell in an Excel document generated with PHPExcel with:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimensionByColumn('C')->setWidth('10');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimensionByColumn('C')->setAutoSize(false);
```

but that does not works.

What is the method that I need to call here?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

It's a subtle difference, but this works fine for me:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(10);
```

Notice, the difference between `getColumnDimensionByColumn` and `getColumnDimension`

Also, I'm not even setting AutoSize and it works fine.

Comment: How can I set the wordwrap property to particular column. It would be useful for me if you know. Thanks!

Comment: It's been a while since I have worked with PHPExcel, but I believe you want 'setWrapText'. example:   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A6')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);

Comment: Jahmic is right. AutoSize is set to false on all columns by default, so it's not necessary to do it with code.

Answer (score 13):

setAutoSize method must come before setWidth:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimensionByColumn('C')->setAutoSize(false);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimensionByColumn('C')->setWidth('10');
```

Comment: AutoSize:false is required in order to set a width

Comment: getColumnDimensionByColumn() expects a 0-based column index, not a column name. (from the Worksheet class: "@param string $pColumn Numeric column coordinate of the cell")

Answer (score 9):

hi i got the same problem..
add 0.71 to excel cell width value and give that value to the

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(10);
```

eg: 
A Column width = 3.71 (excel value)

give column width = 4.42

will give the output file with same cell width.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(4.42);
```

hope this help

Answer (score 8):

autoSize for column width set as bellow. It works for me.

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

Tha is because **getColumnDimensionByColumn** receives the column index (an integer starting from 0), not a string.

The same goes for **setCellValueByColumnAndRow**

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(false);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(10);
```

be sure to add `setAuzoSize(false)`, **before** the `setWidth();` as Rolland mentioned

Comment: Please don't add duplicate answer like Rolland have already defined

Comment: yeah but it's working with getColumnDimension and not getColumnDimensionByColumn

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid You might want to check again. It's not even close to being a duplicate answer, since it implements completely other methods.

Answer (score 4):

This way is much easier to adjust the size of the columns automatically.

```
foreach (range('A', 'I') as $letra) {            
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($letra)->setAutoSize(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to set the column width is by using the line as posted by Jahmic, however it is important to note that additionally, you have to apply styling **after** adding the data, and not before, otherwise on some configurations, the column width is not applied