# Lock column width in PhpExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

In PHPExcel it's quite easy to set the width of a column but I would like to lock the width of all columns after setting it. Just like locking the content of certain cells I would like to lock the width of some columns. I tried locking the column width by making a whole column read only but this did not work.

This is what I am trying to achieve: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.misc/thoekXp4FP0

Comment: Please check this [Setting width of spreadsheet cell using PHPExcel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788472/setting-width-of-spreadsheet-cell-using-phpexcel)

Comment: This topic only describes setting the width but not how to lock it.